# Loading Image into Control button VC++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am doing a dialog based application in VC++ 2010, where I am using different control buttons for different languages and I want to load different `.png` files into the button dynamically, But I am unable to load, please help me.

Comment: Could you show us what are you doing? Maybe we'll be able to find out the problem if we can se your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Look here for a good answer: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/bmpbtn.htm

Hope this helps